# Can be defined as string column to process in tbl_summary in r

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm trying to use tbl_summary in R.
I need to pass as input variable the list of columns to use in "add_p (include = ... )"
Is there a way for do it ???

thanks in advance
A

```
tmp=c(-age, -stage, -grade)

  trial %>% 
    select(trt, stage, age, grade, response) %>% 
    tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
    add_p( include = tmp )
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a vector of characters and `any_of` or `all_of` you could do:

```
library(gtsummary)

tmp <- c("age", "stage", "grade")

trial %>% 
  select(trt, stage, age, grade, response) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_p( include = !any_of(tmp) )
```

[image]